# how to solve mathematical expectation in hackerrank 20/20 hack february 2014

Tags: math

So this problem was given in [Hackerrank 20/20 hack february](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/feb14/challenges/mathematical-expectation) :

> Let’s consider a random permutation p1, p2, …, pN of numbers 1, 2, …, N and calculate the value F=(X2+…+XN-1)^K, where Xi equals 1 if one of the following two conditions holds: pi-1 < pi > pi+1 or pi-1 > pi < pi+1 and Xi equals 0 otherwise. What is the expected value of F?
>
> Constraints: 1000 <= N <= 10^9, 1 <= K <= 5

I thought it was [Eulerian number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) related problem. As the contest is over,I can see the solutions. But I don't understand any of them. Is there any tricks?

Comment: Apparently the solutions are only visible to registered users (i.e., I can't see them). Can you link to/post some of the solutions here (if that wouldn't violate the TOS of that site)? What don't you understand about them?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard sorry for the delay. I asked a user if i could share his code. I am waiting for his reply. As soon as I get it, I will share. As of hint, it is a O(1) solution.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Code sharing is against their terms of services. So I can't help there.But you can sign up and see the solutions there. I have seen the solution of rknoll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so a few words about my "solution" ;)
What I basically did:
1) write a brute force solver (obviously for N << 20)
    -> this solver won't handle high values of N, as given in the constraints
2) analyze the output of the solutions to these (invalid) inputs
    -> observe that with K=1, the output follows a straight line
    -> K=2, is a quadratic function
    -> K=3, is a cubic function, and so on
3) find the parameters for each function (K=1 - 5) by using a solver, or how I did it, wolfram alpha ;)
    -> additionally I "normalized" each parameter to only have one division afterwards
4) use any programming language / big integer class to solve the correct inputs in O(1)
I'm pretty sure that one can come up with these parameters in a very clever way, but for me, during the contest, this solution was easy and fast enough without having to think too much about the "why" ;)